# Hypernym for "business" and "private individual"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

An example sentence:

> Whether, and how much VAT is collected depends on your _________ (private or business) and the country you are located in.

Both formal and informal words are welcome. As long as it's commonly understood in the English-speaking community.

Comment: "Private or business" can pertain to many things, such as addresses, phone numbers,  interests, income, automobile, intended use, etc.  So this question is really about VAT, not English.  If you want to fill in the blank with a synonym, and then ask for another word that is more precise or better in some way,  it would be a better question.

Comment: As @TimRomano says, your private or business _what_? In _car type_, _car_ is the answer. So what would you substitute for _car_?

Comment: I may not have expressed my question correctly. Sorry for that. I'm looking for a term here, similar to "customer type". Only without having to use the word "customer". As there may be customers that are registered companies, but also private individuals.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, and the amount depends not on the seller's status but on the buyer's status, I would say "...depends on the *type of customer* you have sold to..." since I know of no one word that means "type of customer".

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, I think you now understand what I'm looking for. Something like "marital status" is to "married or single".

Comment: What's wrong with VAT-status then?

Comment: Is "VAT-status" a common term? I haven't seen it in use before. Doesn't it refer to the status of VAT number registration? As in: VAT-status: Valid / Invalid / Active / Inactive

Comment: What is with, the punctuation of, the example sen,tence? The, comma makes, no sense!

Comment: You have a sence of humor sir. Please feel free to edit and correct. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about these entities as *taxpayers,* rather than as *customers,* why not just substitute the former for the latter term in your own formula, so as to come up with *taxpayer type?*

In my country (USA), thanks to a perverse legal doctrine, a possible hypernym for both corporations and private individuals is *persons,* but then, my country appears to have an insuperable political aversion to VAT as well.